# LaTeXt PDF file not opening

Tags: latex

I have a LaTeXt file, I downloaded MacTeX, this is my first time for a class. That's the only program I downloaded. I opened TeXShop and wrote the following

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Introduction to LaTeX}
\author{Abdulahad Ghuman}
\date{March 3, 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{What is LaTeX}
\begin{itemsize}
\item LaTeX is used to prepare documents with high-quality typesetting
\item LaTeX is pronounced as Lay-tech not La=tex
\item LaTeX is used for technical or scientific documents
\end{itemsize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Why use LaTeX}
\begin{itemsize}
\item Easily accommodates academic use
\item Predefined layouts make documents look professional
\item Mathematical symbols and equations are easily integrated
\item Footnotes and bibliographies can also be easily made
\item Creates more beautiful documents
\item Portable and compatible among multiple devices
\end{itemsize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{How to install LaTeX for Windows}
\begin{itemsize}
\item Download MiKTeX which is a typesetting system for Windows
\item Download a text editor such as WinEdit, however, WinEdit costs $30
\end{itemsize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{How to install LaTeX for Mac}
\begin{itemsize}
\item Download TexShop which includes everything
\item Alternatively you can download MacTeX
\end{itemsize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Basic format for LaTeX documents}
\begin{itemsize}
\item The preamble includes Documentclass and Packages
\item The front matter can include the title, author, date, etc
\item The body includes the content of the document
\item Optionally, you can also include a bibliography
\end{itemsize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The PDF does not open, I get the error "It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize." Do I need a special program to use beamer? Is that the issue, I only downloaded MacTeX. There's also a program called LaTeXiT. Also on a side note, how can I add aesthetics? After my file actually opens.

EDIT: My Mac version is 10.15.4 and I see "To Obtain Older Versions of MacTeX If You Are Running Mac OS 10.3 through 10.12, click here". Is that the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

- `$` is a special character for latex to start inline math mode. To actually type a $, use `\$`
- it should be `itemize` and not `itemsize`

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Introduction to LaTeX}
\author{Abdulahad Ghuman}
\date{March 3, 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{What is LaTeX}
\begin{itemize}
\item LaTeX is used to prepare documents with high-quality typesetting
\item LaTeX is pronounced as Lay-tech not La=tex
\item LaTeX is used for technical or scientific documents
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Why use LaTeX}
\begin{itemize}
\item Easily accommodates academic use
\item Predefined layouts make documents look professional
\item Mathematical symbols and equations are easily integrated
\item Footnotes and bibliographies can also be easily made
\item Creates more beautiful documents
\item Portable and compatible among multiple devices
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{How to install LaTeX for Windows}
\begin{itemize}
\item Download MiKTeX which is a typesetting system for Windows
\item Download a text editor such as WinEdit, however, WinEdit costs \$30
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{How to install LaTeX for Mac}
\begin{itemize}
\item Download TexShop which includes everything
\item Alternatively you can download MacTeX
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Basic format for LaTeX documents}
\begin{itemize}
\item The preamble includes Documentclass and Packages
\item The front matter can include the title, author, date, etc
\item The body includes the content of the document
\item Optionally, you can also include a bibliography
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I still get the same issue, lemme try on another device

Comment: @CactusSlat Try to delete all the auxiliary files and then compile again. How exactly do you compile?

Comment: @CactusSlat you can try it here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/thssqqxhygdh

Comment: HUH. HOW DID YOUR WEBSITE WORK BUT MY THING DOESN'T? I open TeXShop typeset, LaTeX and then gave it a name. Lemme try deleting all my files and trying again

Comment: Hey guys, I deleted all my files and made it again. It worked, thank you!

Comment: @CactusSlat Great to hear! Have a lot of fun with beamer!  https://www.learnlatex.org/ might also be interesting for you